# Should i handle the missing values of both train and test dataset using a function of train dataset

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I have splitted my dataset into **train** and **test** dataset. both datasets have missing values in the column 'age'. For the **training** dataset I applied a function that will handle the missing values with the mean by considering other columns like 'sex' and 'designation'. I have hardcoded the mean values by looking at sns.boxplot

```
def imp_age(col):
age=col[0]
desg=col[1]
sex=col[2]


if pd.isnull(age):
    if desg==1:
        return 41 
    elif desg==2:
        if sex==0:
            return 33
        else:
            return 38
    else:
        if sex==0:
            return 23
        else:
            return 22
else:
    return age
```

Now to handle missing values in the 'age' column of the **Test** dataset, should I apply the same method which was designed for the training dataset or should I create a new function and with mean values of the test dataset

Comment: Don't code this manually, you'll most likely oversimplify and get it wrong. Train a `regression` algo from entries with `age`, and use it to predict `age` when missing. Repeat approach with `classification/regression` algos for other missing features (if any), finally split in `training + validation + test` sets, see why: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_sets. Note that if multiple missing features, there might be a notion of dependence (eg `age` could help predict some `disease`, so if both are missing, start with `age`)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1):

of course you should handle the missing data in both training and testing using only the training data , if you apply each one separately then you assume you will have some information about testing data in inference time , which is wrong , because when the model will be published you won't have any kind of statistical information except the coming sample .

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to apply the same method which was designed for the training dataset. However, since train, test datasets are samples from same data and you are calculating mean, there shouldnt be much difference if you do that separately in train and test

Answer (score 0):

I think before splitting data into train and test sets for the "Age" column apply a function that will handle the missing values with the mean or median, then split the data.